# Bxslider - the page design needs two of the "Next" / "Prev" controls

Tags: jquery

The page design I'm working on needs two of the "Next" / "Prev" controls
If I .clone with jQuery only the html is cloned. The clones are not clickable.
How do I achieve this with jQuery

```
<div class="slider_con slider-1">
    <div class="slider">
                .....         
  </div>
</div>

$( ".slider-1 .bx-next" ).clone().appendTo( ".slider-1 .bx-wrapper" );
```

This jQuery clone the link (.bx-next) but it is not cloning the behavior

Comment: Hi, can you add some code snippet to your question please ? Thanks

Comment: Do you know what's the event they call or the function to execute the next/prev commands?

Comment: Sorry my javascript skills are not the best
https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/blob/master/src/js/jquery.bxslider.js